# Error using Visual Studio XML IntelliSense for URL Rewrite 2.0: Failed to open file XML\Schema\DotNetConfig.xsd

Tags: visual-studio-2010, url-rewriting

I have downloaded Visual Studio XML IntelliSense for URL Rewrite 2.0  and tried to install it thru command prompt but it not working …its shows

> Failed to open file XML\Schema\DotNetConfig.xsd Make sure that the
>   script run in elevated command prompt

This is what i have done so far...

1. Changed `%VS90COMNTOOLS%` to `%VS100COMNTOOLS%`
2. Ran `cscript UpdateSchemaCache.js` as Administrator

But nothing is working.  I have VS2010 version.

I have followed the instruction on this link and I am not sure what am i doing wrong here:
http://ruslany.net/2010/04/visual-studio-xml-intellisense-for-url-rewrite-2-0/

Comment: There's a bunch of comments on that blog post, including one that references the error you're getting.  Have you tried all of the suggestions posted there?

Answer (score 1):

Open UpdateSchemaCache.js for Editing and Change This  TO `%VS90COMNTOOLS%`

```
 var vs9CommonTools = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%VS90COMNTOOLS%");
```

if U Use V2010 -> `%VS100COMNTOOLS%`

if U Use V2012 -> `%VS110COMNTOOLS%`

Then Go to  the Error Index

```
if ( targetXml.load( dotNetSchemaFile ) == 0 )
{
    WScript.Echo("Failed to open file " + dotNetSchemaFile + ". Make sure that the script is run in the elevated command prompt.");
    WScript.Quit(1);
}
```

your  `dotNetSchemaFile` is missing that's only  you got this error.the code check the file in invalid location so u will change the  path

***OLD PATH***

> var dotNetSchemaDir = vs9CommonTools.substring( 0,
>   vs9CommonTools.indexOf( "Common7\Tools" ) ) + "Xml\Schemas\";

**NEW PATH**

> var dotNetSchemaDir = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\";

Comment: DotNetConfig.xsd file path may vary from system to system. I would suggest to search the file name in Microsoft Visual Studio <version> folder and then specify the actual path of file in UpdateSchemaCache.js as suggested by @Karthikeyan.

Answer (score 0):

Open UpdateSchemaCache.js for editing and change this `%VS90COMNTOOLS%` to this `%VS100COMNTOOLS%`